# Using base64-encoded images in Google Vision API to detect handwriting and text in files

Tags: base64, ocr, google-vision

I see google API has 3 ways of OCR-ing text from an image/document:

1. detect text
2. detect handwriting
3. detect text in files

(1) allows to upload base-64 image, (2) and (3) forces me to only use a file referenced in google cloud?

Can I use (2) and (3) with base-64 instead?

Answer (score 0):

never mind, found it. Google wants you to upload and save in their cloud TIF/PDF so it can be done offline.

Disappointing.